# What does ～ていく mean here?

Tags: meaning, nuances

> すぐ傍から告げられた言葉に、胸の鼓動がどんどん高鳴りを増していく。

As usual, I have problems understanding ～てくる/いく. I've already studied their meanings, but whenever I encounter them, I don't know which one it is.

He hugs her, and says something romantic, and she thinks that. To me, it means the throbbing is growing more and more, but I'm wondering if I'm wrong and it means the throbbing is growing towards him, in his direction.

Comment: You mean it could be something like 彼は彼女に近づいていく? Your first interpretation is correct, but I don't think these are two ていく, it is more a matter of the meaning of verb whether it contains *towards* sense.

Comment: (I meant just about the ていく in the first sentence above).

Comment: I meant to say that I sometimes don't understand if いく shows a direction or a gradual change from now to the future. It shows a gradual change here, right?

Comment: Yes, but direction is also a gradual change (along a path). Whether it is a direction depends on the verb preceding ていく.